# Are static variables thread safe in the sense that you can read/write from multiple threads without it crashing?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a property defined as:

```
private static MyStaticCache? _myStaticCache;
```

`MyStaticCache` is a class with a string property. Multiple threads can access `_myStaticCache`. If the property is null or the value is old any thread accessing it will get the value from the source and set `_myStaticCache` to that value.

```
public string GetValue()
{
    if (_myStaticCache == null || _myStaticCache.CacheIsStale())
        _myStaticCache = GetValueFromSource();

    return _myStaticCache.Value1;
}
```

No code can or will ever sets `_myStaticCache` back to null.

One can quickly see that it's possible for multiple calls to `GetValueFromSource()` and assignments to `_myStaticCache` if multiple threads run before it is assigned the first time or when it has gone stale.

My question is this. Is there a way that this will cause a crash? Is the assignment of `_myStaticCache` atomic, or could there be a read in the middle of a write?

The fact that the the source method could be called N times in parallel does not really matter. The timeout for the cache is 30 days, and it is very unlikely that multiple threads will run at that exact time although not impossible, and even if there would be 100 threads running in parallel calling it the method would return the same value for each one and be able to handle the load no problem.

Now I could use a Mutex, or wrap the read and write in `lock()` but I'm thinking this would hinder performance for the 99.999% of the time this method is being called, again it will only be null or old every 30 days.

Comment: In a single word: no.

Comment: @user207421 any single word answer on this topic is usually not worth the wasted single word

Comment: Can `GetValueFromSource` return `null`?

Comment: if `value` is a collection it will crash. there are dozens of situations when things dont behave as "expected" when it comes to heavy multi-threading. and even if it wont crash - you will get very tricky race conditions when `value` returned is not what you expected. Oh just read it again - you cannot share a string without synchronization. Period.

Comment: @BoppityBop The top answer proves that it *is* OK under the specific conditions OP asked about. And yes that includes strings - they're immutable so once you've got a reference you're safe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as `MyStaticCache` is a `class` (or interface; basically: a reference-type), you should be fine.

The language specification guarantees that you won't ever get torn references, so no it shouldn't ever crash:

> ### 12.5 Atomicity of variable references
>
> Reads and writes of the following data types shall be atomic: `bool`, `char`, `byte`, `sbyte`, `short`, `ushort`,
> `uint`, `int`, `float`, and reference types. In addition, reads and writes of enum types with an underlying type
> in the previous list shall also be atomic. Reads and writes of other types, including `long`, `ulong`, `double`,
> and `decimal`, as well as user-defined types, need not be atomic. Aside from the library functions designed
> for that purpose, there is no guarantee of atomic read-modify-write, such as in the case of increment or
> decrement.

So as long as you're not concerned about running the slow path multiple times for the initial / stale value, or issues relating to register usage etc : you should be fine.

Personally I'd probably do the `CacheIsStale()` check in a timer (at a frequency of your choosing) that sets the field to `null` when it detects staleness, rather than constantly checking *two* conditions. You could even do the refresh inside the timer callback and set the static field to the new reference instead, so:

```cs
public string GetValue()
    => (_myStaticCache ?? FetchAndAssign()).Value1;
private MyStaticCache FetchAndAssign()
    => _myStaticCache = GetValueFromSource();
private void TimerCallback()
{
    if (_myStaticCache is null || _myStaticCache.CacheIsStale())
        FetchAndAssign();
}
```

Note that we can only comment on `_myStaticCache`; what `.Value1` does is *up to your code*, and may or may not be thread-safe.

Answer (score -1):

You really need to use synchronization (I simply dont believe you have a case for not using it, judging by the question). Even ints and other values types often require some sort of synchronization (eg memory barrier) despite being touted "atomic".

What I would do in your case is to simply wrap all access to your shared object with `ReaderWriterLockSlim` (and also Id suggest to have a singleton instead of static)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim?view=net-5.0

```
private ReaderWriterLockSlim cacheLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

    public MyValueType ReadValue()
    {
        cacheLock.EnterReadLock();
        try
        {
            return myCache.Value1;
        }
        finally
        {
            cacheLock.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }

    public void WriteValue(MyValueType value)
    {
        cacheLock.EnterWriteLock();
        try
        {
            myCache.Value1 = value;
        }
        finally
        {
            cacheLock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }
```